# Select function error in R unable to find an inherited method for function

Tags: r, select, dplyr

```r
    # Perform the inner join operation
        selected_data <- filtered_data %>%
          inner_join(filtered_info, by = "ID") %>%
          select(ID, which(colnames(.) %in% as.character(genes_unique)),       primary_disease)


Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
Calls: %>% -> select -> <Anonymous>
```

Hi, I keep getting this error on a code that worked previously. Please let me know if anyone has input.

Comment: Have you attached the `dplyr` library? Try `library(dplyr)`

Comment: try: `dplyr::select()`